# How to use frozen inference graph to detect objects in an image?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow2.0

I followed some tutorials on object detection with TensorFlow. I managed to train a model on my custom dataset using Colab and downloaded the frozen inference graph. Now I want to use this inference graph on images to detect objects.
From what I have searched soo far, first I have to find out tensor names(not really sure what it means). but the code is like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def load_graph(frozen_graph_filename):
    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="prefix")
    return graph
g = load_graph("inference_graph/frozen_inference_graph.pb")
for op in g.get_operations():
    print(op.values())
```

And these are the last 6 lines:

```
(<tf.Tensor 'prefix/add/y:0' shape=() dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'prefix/add:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'prefix/detection_boxes:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'prefix/detection_scores:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'prefix/detection_classes:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'prefix/num_detections:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32>,)
```

Now how should I proceed? I am using tensorflow 2. I tried to follow some guides but they are very confusing. I am unable to make it work soo far.

Comment: in Tensorflow 2.x frozen graph is no longer supported [see](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.0.0) . if you want to use a frozen graph you should use TF 1.X version

Comment: Not sure what you meant by these "six lines". but you have to define  like `detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')`                                               
and so on..  If you need simple example check out [this](https://github.com/Aziiiz/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10/blob/master/Object_detection_image.py) source code but it is written in TF1.X